# Angular UI bootstrap: how to add first option to select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have the following select schema:

[image]

First: I have input, which filters my select dropbox results

Second: In my result always should be option, when I click it, I want to see modal window (so, even if I enter some text, this option still has to be in my dropbox)

Third...n: default options

Now I have such template:

```
<ui-select ***mysecretoptions***>
  <ui-select-match ***mysecretoptions***>***mysecretoptions***</ui-select-match>

  <ui-select-choices***mysecretoptions***>
    <span ***mysecretoptions***></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

and it works good, but first option hides, when i do some search...

Is it possible to do, and how?

Te first option is shown only when I enter/click ui-select (so it's not displayed as selected or default value of whole selectbox)

Comment: One of the possible way is to hack the select.js of angular ui-select library and add a button template to the uiSelectConfig option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, I do it everyday, check the following:

```
<ui-select ng-model="view.provinceCode" title="Province">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="x.code as x in view.provinces | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="x.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

As you can see in the `repeat`line, you can use any property of your array of objects to be the value of the `ng-model`, once you have done that, you can set the selected item manually.

```
// my controller (javascript)
view.provinceCode = 37;
```

That will set the `ui-select` to the item you established in your controller.

If you don't use the `x.property as x` approximation, if you set the model to the **FULL** object, the result will be the same: the selected property of the `ui-select` will be the one you wanted.

**EDIT:**

I just realised that you asked to put the *first* element of the array, which in your case is even easier...

```
view.provinceCode = view.provinces[0].code;
```

Or, with the full object...

```
view.selectedProvince = view.provinces[0];
```

Comment: this first object should exists in every combination: with search or without. That's the main goal. Btw: clicking of this first object will cause modal window to open

Comment: like first option is: 'create new item'

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I don't really get your point, you asked for selecting the first item of the select, and that's what I answered, if you want some extra behaviour, you can do whatever you like inside a `ng-change` property and you should have specified that as well in your question...

Comment: "Second: In my result always *should be option, when I click it, I want to see modal window* (so, even if I enter some text, this option still has to be in my dropbox)"

all was specified...

i don't asked for selecting first item. please read question one more time